# Domino Designer 8.5 Cascading dropdown (combobox choices will depend on another combobox)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Good day! I have 2 combobox: C1 and C2. C1 have 2 choices: A and B. I want that if I choose A on the C1, D,E,F will be the only choices on C2 and if I choose B, G,H,I will be the choices. What formula can I choose? Thank you. Hopefully, I can get the most basic one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the formula for choices in C2's properties:

```
@If( C1 = "A"; "D":"E":"F"; C1 = "B"; "G":"H":"I"; "something is wrong!");
```

And be sure to set the "Refresh fields on keywords changes" property on C1 and the "Refresh choices on document refresh" property on C2.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I have an additional question? Is it possible to import an excel file to domino designer? How?

Comment: Comment threads on StackOverflow should not be used to ask new questions, especially if they are completely unrelated to the current question. If you have another question, please just create a new question. Better yet, search! There are lots of web pages that discuss importing excel spreadsheet data into Domino.